# routind with dynamic placeholder

Tags: symfony

I've got something special to do with a route.
I juste want to use a route to generate the url.

In a bundle I've got a route with path like /folder/{foo}/

```
route_name:
    path: /folder/{foo}/
```

I want to override this route with /nosymfonyapp/%routing_id.{foo}%/

```
route_name:
    path: /nosymfonyapp/%routing_id.{foo}%/
```

With that in my config.yaml

```
parameters:
    routing_id.bar: 1-bar 
    routing_id.barbar: 2-barbar
```

Is something like that is possible ?

For the curious one, the route in the bundle define a certain type of content. I want to overide the link of this type of content with a link to an other part of my app that is not in symfony
ex :

```
{{ path('route_name', {'foo': 'bar'}) }} generate /folder/bar/
```

I want

```
{{ path('route_name', {'foo': 'bar'}) }} generate /nosymfonyapp/1-bar/
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The router in Symfony by default can only generate urls for Symfony routes and not for external paths.
You can create your own custom route loader that does what you want:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/custom_route_loader.html